# Launch Foursquare app via BlackBerry mobile web link

Tags: blackberry, foursquare

Is there a way to create a link on a web page to launch the BlackBerry native version of the Foursquare app?  I'd like to open a particular venue in the app, but I can't even find a way to cause the app to launch at all.

On Android and iOS there are URL schemes to accomplish this, like on this page:
https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client

But, that page does not address web links from BlackBerry devices.  In particular, I'm interested in BlackBerry OS 6/7 handsets.

foursquare: URLs just fail with a not-supported error message, and http links to foursquare.com just open in the same browser window.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the page at https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client, under "BlackBerry Native App Integration", you can find instructions on how to launch the native foursquare app from other BlackBerry apps.